# Difference between handler and listener

Tags: netty

I'm new to netty.
I have a question about difference between handler and listener.

When I write something to remote, I can use the following two things to do more jobs after write operation is completed.

1. implement writeComplete callback on handler
2. write().addListener() and implement operationComplete() on listener

What's difference between them? If they are same, what's better?

Thanks in advance.